What is this movie about animal friendship before 1989?
I remember this movie I watched as a child that was about some animals in the forest (I think a bear and a fox or a wolf) that met each other as cubs and grew up together playing without knowing they were enemies as adults.  In the end, the two animals had to part their ways because they were not able to be together anymore.   
The movie is live action, so it is not animated. I am not 100% sure what animals it was but a bear comes to mind. It was filmed in a forest.
I watched it before 1989 because I was a child, about 5 years old. I've been thinking it could be from the 70s as well. I believe the animals never spoke in the movie (voice over by people) and it was mostly action and music.
Any idea would greatly be appreciated.

Could it be a film from long before 1989?

Could very well be.  I been thinking it could be from the 70s as well.  But any ideas would be helpful.

The one I had in mind is even older than that, actually. I'll put it up.

You might be after the Disney film Nikki, Wild Dog of the North from 1961. It's about a Malamute puppy (that resembles a wolf) whose owner tethers it to a bear cub. When they're separated from the owner, the dog and bear must learn to survive in the forest together and eventually become friends. They later go their separate ways when it's time for the grown bear to hibernate. Here's a clip from the movie:




That movie Nikki, Wild dog from the North sure looks like the video!!! I am gonna watch it as soon as I can. Thanks Walt.

@kove454 if you got the rite answer, then better to select it by clicking on rite sign rather then posting thank you  comments as an answer.

Ok thanks. I did watch this movie it was close but not the one.  I will keep searching. If anyone has any more ideas that would be great.

A shot in the dark here:
It is possible you're looking for "The Adventures of Milo and Otis"
What fits:

The time period of the film in question: "The Adventures of Milo and Otis" was released in 1986 (before 1989).
Live action movie with unlikely animal friends: Milo is a cat, and Otis is a dog. Typically these are natural enemies, but being introduced to each-other as a Kitten and a Puppy, they grew up as friends.
Animals don't speak, but are voiced over by people: The animals in "The Adventures of Milo and Otis" never spoke but their thoughts and actions where narrated by one person.
The animals part ways in the end: "The Adventures of Milo and Otis" actually ends on a happy note, but the two animals part ways when they each encounter a female of their kind. They separate to form their own families, but still retain their friendship.
There are other wild animals in the movie: Both Milo and Otis encounter a number of wild animals (Bears, Foxes, Deer, Owls, Snakes, Pigs, Raccoons, and Sea Gulls).


I don't think its the show, but I will watch it and see.

Yea it isnt the movie I was looking for thanks anyways.
